# How would you PHPUnit test a Wordpress function containing get_post_meta()?

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit

I've just start learning PHPUnit with Wordpress. I have a widget that gets post data  from and metadata of it.

My Code Looks like the following:

```
           if ($postMeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature_news_colours_overlay')) {
                $colourOverlay = $postMeta['0'];
            }
          $items[] = [
                'title' => $title,
                'url' => get_permalink($post->ID),
                'description' => $content,
                'colourOverlay' => $colourOverlay,
            ];
```

The widget is getting data from a `feature_news_colours_overlay` custom_field for the post. In my PhpUnit test i can add the following to make it test the if conditions.

```
          $post = new \stdClass();
          $post->post_title = 'Some title text to test.';
          $post->ID = 1;
          $GLOBALS['post_meta'][0] = '#FFCC00';
```

This actually tests my Item array with an assert:

```
'title' => 'Some title text to test.',
'url' => 'http://something..',
'description' => 'test desc',
'colourOverlay' => '#FFoooo'
```

This actually testes my if condition, as i see this is not a standard way if i have to check more then 1 posts i cant actually test with a GLOBAL value.

> $GLOBALS['post_meta'][0] = '#FFCC00';

Is there any way i could add a mock meta value to each post so as to check the if condition.?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the post ID you're testing into $post_id, then

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'your_meta_key', 'your_test_value' );
```

in your testing code just before your assertions should do the trick.